# Swift, get variable name from a string

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, pointers, swift

I have a question. I know that this can be done in Ruby, not sure about Swift, but never did anything similar.
What I'm working on is a program that works similar to this: if the user writes in a TextView "a + b", my code should elaborate the value of the sum between the variable "a" and "b".
What I mean is, how can I get variable names from a string? Is it possible at all?

If it's not, I'd use a switch (variable names are limited), but I'd need to "connect" a variable to the one written by the user. In the example, if the user writes "a + b", my sum function is something like "sum(par1,par2)", so, how can I make variable "par1" point to "a" and "par2" point to "b"? I can do that with pointers right? Is there any other way?

I'm not sure I've been clear, but it's quite hard to explain

Comment: You need to distinguish between the variables in your application and the data in your application (which in this case represent 'variables').  A `Dictionary` is probably a good data store to use.

Comment: You should probably post some code demonstrating your work to solve the problem to this point, but, as @paulw said, a dictionary is the most likely repository for your multiple variables, using the strings from your text field as keys and your variable values as values.

Answer (score 1):

Check this out. You can do with `NSExpression` and `KVC`.

```
class myclass:NSObject {

    var a = 10;
    var b = 20;

    override init() {
        super.init();
    }


}

var obj = myclass();

// Expression from user
var expr:NSString = "a+b" ;

//Operators..
let opSet = NSMutableCharacterSet()
opSet.addCharactersInString("+-*/");


let components:NSArray = expr.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(opSet)
let uniqueChars:NSSet = NSSet(array: components)

for variable in uniqueChars
{
    expr = expr.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString ( variable as String,
    withString  : NSString(format: "%d", obj.valueForKey(variable as String) as Int),
    options     : NSStringCompareOptions.LiteralSearch,
    range       : NSMakeRange(0,expr.length)         );

}


var result: AnyObject = NSExpression(format: expr).expressionValueWithObject(nil, context: nil)

print (result);
```