# How get value from variables of similar names

Tags: swift

Sequential variable names defined. I want to reach a variable relative to the corresponding value.

```
 var code = 2 // 5, 6, ... // corresponding values
    var name : String

    var name1 : String = "Aaaaaa"
    var name2 : String = "Bbbbbb"
    // var name3
    // var name4 ...

    name = "name" + String(code)  // name = "Bbbbb" ??
```

I do not get the results I wanted.
I hope i explained correctly. Thank you for your help.

Comment: That is what arrays are for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unlike in Objective-C, you can't access a variable by a `String` of its name in Swift. In your case, you might want to just use an array:

```
var code = 2 // 5, 6, ... // corresponding values
var names = ["Aaaaaa", "Bbbbbb"]
var name = names[code - 1] // "Bbbbbb"
```

If you really want to do it dynamically from a string name, you'll have to bridge to Objective-C, for example:

```
class SomeObject: NSObject {
    var name1 : String = "Aaaaaa"
    var name2 : String = "Bbbbbb"

    func getName(code: Int) -> String {
        let name = valueForKey("name" + String(code)) as! String  // "Bbbbbb"
        return name
    }
}

SomeObject().getName(2) // "Bbbbbb"
```

Of course, by doing this, you lose a lot of the safety that Swift provides.

Comment: @EricD as I understand the OP wants to access different named _properties_ given a runtime code. For this, the above conformance to `NSObject` and subsequent use of `self.valueForKey` is the only option to use. As noted in this answer, however, we totally leave Swifts renowned type safety using this method.

Comment: @Aaron Brager , you're great! :) Thank you so much. It was good. Hopefully not be safety problem. Because I have no idea about safety. Thanks again.

Comment: @Mahmut For an example of why this is unsafe, try setting `name2` to anything besides a `String` - for example, `1234` or `nil`.

Comment: @Aaron Brager ,   Yes I understood. I take necessary precautions related to it. Thank you.

Comment: According to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26860423/1677912) (which is probably a duplicate question), you _can_ get a Swift variable value by a string of its name. Not easily, not elegantly, perhaps... but it is possible.

Comment: @Mogsdad That solution uses `valueForKey` by bridging to Objective-C, just like mine.

Comment: Yes... underlining that the question is a duplicate. Feel free to VTC this one.

Comment: Sure, I was just disagreeing with the first half of your comment which implies a disagreement with my statement that it's impossible in pure Swift.